# Spock unit testing to test the RestTemplate.postForEntity

Tags: groovy, spock

I am new to Spock unit testing framework. I am able to write unit test cases using Spock for simple logics. Now, I am writing the same for a Rest API.

I am using Spring's RestTemplate to hit the GET and POST requests. I have seen number of example in google for GET request(like WireMock). But, there is no enough information to give clarification on how to write test cases for POST requests.

Here is my sample code which is written in Junit. I have to convert the same to Spock (I can do).

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(value = "integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class LocalControllerTest {

  @Rule
  public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(9999);

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockRemoteService();
  }

  @Test
  public void testLocalServiceWithMockedRemoteService() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/localService", String.class);
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("Input : request from client endpoint, Message : mocked remote service response", response.getBody());
  }

  private void mockRemoteService() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/remote"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .withBodyFile("remoteServiceResponse.json")));
  }

}
```

Main issue is, even though I wrote the test cases, the call is actually happening to the service (Which is at my localhost) which I am not expecting to happen it. Is there any way to Mock up the data locally and make the call to dummy endpoint for POST request using Spock framework? I don't know much about to mock a dummy endpoint.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and why it is useful if you are looking for helpful answers here or anywhere else. Please show some code, help the community reproduce your problem. We all like to see what you tried, then we can help you much better.

Comment: apologies. now, I have added my sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but a real MCVE ideally comprises not just the test itself but also the class(es) under test. The advantage would be that I could actually compile and run your test. :-) Same goes for Spring configuration. I am not a Spring user, I am more of a Spock guy. But I am sure someone would be able to help, even if I wasn't. But with a complete MCVE I might be able to as well.